# comparison theorem of integral from negative infinity to positive infinity.

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I need help determining whether $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2+x^{\frac{1}{3}}-1}{e^{2x}}dx$$ converges or diverges.

I know that it diverges since when you approach $-\infty$ the function will shoot up. My plan is to consider [$-\infty$,2] since the function will be greater than 0 as it has a root at around -1.4.

However I am having trouble bounding the numerator from below. I know I can make the denominator bigger by making it $e^{3x}$ since $e^{2x} \le e^{3x}$ but the numerator is what is troubling me.

Any suggestions would help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write the integrand as $(x^2+x^{\frac{1}{3}}-1)e^{-2x}$ and show that both factors are bigger than $1$ for sufficiently negative $x$.

Comment: Is it a property that if 2 functions diverge then their product diverges?

Comment: It is a property that if two numbers are greater than one then their product is greater than one. This implies that the function is bounded away from zero, and that in turn implies that the integral can't converge.

Comment: @MarkViola There's a difference between 'unbounded' and 'bounded away from zero' - the former allows for sign changes that the latter (at least for continuous functions, which is an implicit assumption that I should have made explicit) does not.